# Не создается объект пользователя

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Модель пользователя:

```js
const user = new Schema({
    photo: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: '/no-photo.jpg'
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    posts: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'post' }]
})
```

Модель поста:

```js
const post = new Schema({
    userId: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user'
    },
    user: {
        type: Object,
        ref: 'user'
    },
    text: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    likes: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
        required: true
    },
    dislikes: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
        required: true
    },
    comments: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'comment' }]
})
```

Добавляю пост вот так:

```js
router.post('/post/:id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { text } = req.body;
    const findUser = await User.findById(req.params.id);

    const newPost = new Post({
      userId: findUser._id,
      user: findUser,
      text,
      date: new Date(),
      comments: []
    })

    await newPost.save();

    res.redirect('/');
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: e.message });
  }
})
```

Нужно, чтобы создался объект пользователя, в посте, который этот пост и написал, а у меня 2 id: Нужно, чтобы вместо `user : 60c4c82456e0d31d44337344` был объект пользователя. Я новичок в бэкенде, поэтому могу тупить в некоторых вещах

```js
_id : 60c4c83456e0d31d44337345
likes : 0
dislikes : 0
comments : Array
userId : 60c4c82456e0d31d44337344
user : 60c4c82456e0d31d44337344
text : "message"
date : 2021-06-12T14:44:04.539+00:00
__v : 0
```

Comment: а зачем делать и поле с ид пользователя и с данными пользователя? Можете оставить ид и просто делать lookup по этому ид в юзерах.

Answer (score 0):

В модели поста:

```js
user: {
    type: Object,
    required: true
}
```

И при создании поста передал объект пользователя